# webdriverwait.element_to_be_clickable.click() doesn't work with high poll frequency

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a URL and I make the script click on a button_1 which opens a pop-up_1 with a button_2.
For clicking on button_2 I am using this to be sure the button_2 is ready to be clicked:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "anyPATH"))).click()
```

And it works. But as I wanted to make it work as fast as possible I changed the parameter `poll_frequency` to less than 0.5 (which I think is the default value), like this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5, poll_frequency=0.1).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "anyPATH"))).click()
```

Then, button_2 never gets a click although popup_1 gets opened. My guess is that, when `poll_frequency` value is too low, `WebDriverwait` starts to work before popup_1 is completely ready and
never finds button_2 because it is probably searching in the parent URL (not the popup_1).

I inserted time.sleep(0.5) before the webdriverwait and then it works again with poll_frequency=0.1, but is there a funcion/method so I don't have to use time.sleep and with poll_frequency at low values?

Comment: The way `WebDriverWait` works is that it immediately tries the condition (element is clickable), if the condition is true it clicks. If it's not true, it waits for the polling time (default 500ms) before trying the condition again. With your changes, at best you would save 400ms (assuming the condition is NOT true on first attempt but true on the second). My guess is that if you ran your code 100 times, you wouldn't see a difference. 400ms on a web UI script of any length is going to be imperceptible.

Comment: Also, assuming that your popup is part of the original page and not a separate tab that opens in the browser, you guess about `poll_frequency` is not correct. It will continue to poll the DOM until the condition is true or the timeout is hit. So even if popup_1 is not present, it won't fail until the timeout. Now if the click is failing because it's timing out... that's a whole other thing. You didn't post the error message on fail... you should edit the question and post the full error message. That may give more detail on what the issue actually is.

Comment: But I really need to make it work as fast as possible (not the whole script but these 2 or 3 lines I wrote above). If I could lower those 0.5 s from time.sleep it would be great. Maybe some method (before the webdriverwait.elemento_to_be_clickable) which assures the pop-up window is accesible.

Comment: popup_1 is present but button_2 never gets clicked when poll frequency=0.1, and there is no error message

Comment: It's as if the script gets stuck there

Comment: And yes, the popup is part of the original page (not separate) and the browser is chrome. For clarification.

Comment: I don't suppose you can share the page and the scenario so we can give it a try?

Comment: I know you said that if the popup appears in the original window it should work as it is but maybe I can try to switch to the popup window first if that is possible at all

Comment: If your code is working with a 500ms polling time, switching to the popup is not required.